# Cisco configure RADIUS with local account same time

Tags: cisco, network, authentication, radius

In LAB i am working on Cisco authentication with freeradius and everything works but i want my cisco switch first lookup in radius and if user didn't find then it go to local database.

currently i am seeing cisco switch asking radius and if no-user found then its not looking into local database.

Reason i need local account incase anything go wrong with radius or any condition players not able to login, i want atleast admin can login on switch and perform network activity.

following is my config:

```
radius-server host 10.10.10.10 key 7 "supersecter" authentication accounting
aaa group server radius FREERADIUS
    server 10.10.10.10
    use-vrf management
    source-interface mgmt0
```

in radius i have following config:

```
ops             Cleartext-Password := 123456
                Service-Type = NAS-Prompt-User,
                Cisco-AVPair = "shell:roles=network-operator",
                Cisco-AVPair += "shell:priv-lvl=1"
```

I am successfully able to login with `ops` account but not able to login with local account like `admin`.

EDIT: I have tested if radius is fail/dead then it will go to local account but i want both working together not just in dead senario.

is it possible or not to have fallback to local?

Comment: If any of the answers have solved your problem, please don't forget to vote accordingly and mark a solution as accepted so this question doesn't continue to come up as unresolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do that. You would have to set different authentication methods for different interfaces. Something like VTY 0-4 use RADIUS, VTY 5-15 use local accounts. Normally, you'd use RADIUS or similar for VTY but then leave Console to authenticate locally since you have to be physically at the device or connected through an IP KVM/KMM to use it.

For NX-OS, you can follow the steps in the guide found [here](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus9000/sw/6-x/security/configuration/guide/b_Cisco_Nexus_9000_Series_NX-OS_Security_Configuration_Guide/b_Cisco_Nexus_9000_Series_NX-OS_Security_Configuration_Guide_chapter_0111.html).  This article is for Nexus 9k devices but the steps are the same for other models.  If you click on Configuring AAA, there is a sub-link to show you how to configure Console access to use local authentication.

Comment: I forgot to mention in question that i am running Cisco nexus switches which doesn't have option to specify `line vty 0 4`

Comment: Thanks! but one more problem we don't have console to all of the switches :( all i am trying to find best way to handle this when some case my radius go zombie or any underlying component busted in that case my NOC people can get access of switches and don't get block..

Comment: @Satish Normally for remote Console access, you use an IP KVM/KMM solution that's connected to a different circuit (Out Of Band managment) so it isn't affected by outages affecting the rest of the network.

Comment: I can't help with simply not being allowed to access the console of some devices - that's a company policy issue.

Comment: Thanks, I believe cisco doesn't like that idea, you can't use both database same time so i think i have to live with that. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Satish I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. I have many devices (including Nexus) configured to use RADIUS for SSH while simultaneously using local accounts for console access.

Comment: In your scenario it will work but in my case i don't have remote console cables on all switches so no point to setup local console access. I was trying to find out if Cisco nexus look into RADIUS db first and if (no user found) then start looking into local db but cisco doesn't like that idea for security reason. Cisco only fallback when RADIUS is dead  period.

Comment: @Satish Oh. I see. Yeah, sorry, there's just no way to do it like you want.  Sorry.